# S3 select query vs iterator for counting the lines of S3 file?

Tags: java, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, optimization

I have a question: To count the number of line in a `file of size <= 128Mb` stored in AWS: S3 bucket, Should i use `S3 SELECT` feature or should i `download the file and then iterate` it to get line count. catch here is that file which i am downloading from S3 is being used later.

what do you suggest?

Comment: This : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html is ideal for your use case. You can perform a count of the number of records (lines) in a file. If working with larger files, use the API. ***Note*** : It  works even with GZIP files.

Comment: Hi, @Amitkumar for file size >= 128MB, i saw "awssdk" documentation but couldn't find anything like "s3 select", its just have .getobject()